# How to search for files with a specific extention from a specifically given directory and all subdirectories

Tags: java, file

Just for my own learning, i am trying to find all mp3 files in my music collection and finding all the tracks which do not have id3v2 tags. My code gives me information about the directory i specify, but it doesn't look for the mp3 files in subdirectories. Although i can see that it recognises the directories as i can print them out. Please see my code below. I am very sorry if the formatting of the code is not correct. I am blind and using a screen reader and the formatter on this site is not very accessible to me.

```
public static int numberOfUntaggedTracks(String directory) throws UnsupportedTagException, InvalidDataException, IOException {
    int untaggedTracks = 0;
    File f = new File(directory);
    File l[] = f.listFiles();
    for (File x: l) {
    if (x.isHidden() || !x.canRead())
        continue;
    if (x.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("testing" + x.getPath());
        numberOfUntaggedTracks(x.getPath());
    } else if (x.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
        Mp3File song = new Mp3File(x.getPath());

        if (song.hasId3v1Tag() == false) {
        untaggedTracks++;
        }
        //end of else if checking for .mp3 extension                
    }
    //end of for loop
    }
    return untaggedTracks;
}
```

Comment: recursively use file filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileUtils from apatche commons-io has a listFiles method that should do what you need.

The method takes two  IOFileFilter instances that you can use to filter files (mp3 files in your case) and to filter sub directories (so you can control which directories to include in your search).

To make your code work just change `numberOfUntaggedTracks(x.getPath());` to `untaggedTracks += numberOfUntaggedTracks(x.getPath());`

Comment: But what i have hear, are you able to explain why it doesn't work? I can see it is printing out the directories, so should it not run the same method again on the directory?

Comment: your doing it correctly, but you are missing one simple step of adding the result of numberOfUntaggedTracks(x.getPath()) to untaggedTracks.

Comment: ah. I assumed because that method is rerun, when it gets to the else if which finds all files ending with .mp3 it will add it to the untaggedTracks variable. So is this essentially running a new instance of that method each time it comes across a directory? I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It makes sense but its not the way variables work in java, untaggedTracks is local to the function and each call gets a fresh copy of this variable initialized to 0.

Comment: Ah of course i overlooked the initialisation of the variable at the beginning of the method. Thank you for your assistance.